# Exception using Jetty with Cobertura instrumented classes

Tags: log4j, jetty, integration-testing, cobertura

When running Jetty with the instrumented classes by Cobertura, I get the following exception:

```
NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.xml.XMLLayout.setProperties(Z)V
```

Could it be because of version conflicts because the log4j Cobertura is using?
What should I do in the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that adding the `cobertura-runtime` artifact to my `pom` and not the `cobertura` artifact solved this issue. `cobertura-runtime` was introduced in-order to remove the `log4j` dependency while running your webapp.

This is the dependency I've added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.4.1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Great!